# Using F#'s built-in async support with *Async() methods

Tags: f#, asynchronous, webclient

How do I use F#'s built-in support for async operations classes exposing the [Event-based Asynchronous Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wewwczdw.aspx) such as *WebClient* class?

```
let Download(url : Uri) =
    let client = new WebClient()
    let html = client.DownloadString(url)
    html
```

When I try to change this to use "let!" in an *async* block (say as described in Soma's recent [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/somasegar/archive/2009/10/09/f-in-vs2010.aspx))

```
let Download(url : Uri) =
    async {
    let client = new WebClient()
    let! html = client.DownloadStringAsync(url)
    return html }
```

I get an error message:

> Type constraint mismatch. The type   unit is not compatible with type  Async<'a> The type 'unit' is not compatible with the type 'Async<'a>'

Edit: I'm really asking about the general question of using *Async() methods, WebClient is just an easy example.  Microsoft [says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228966.aspx) "... you should expose asynchronous features using the Event-based Asynchronous Pattern [ as opposed to BeginFoo()/EndFoo() ] whenever possible ..." so I would think there should be an easy way to consume an arbitrary *Async() method from F#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [WebClient.DownloadStringAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144202%28VS.80%29.aspx) method is part of the .NET framework. It'll raise an event to signal its progress, and its return type is `unit`, so you don't want to use it, and there's no advantage in wrapping it in an `async` object.

The F# PowerPack defines an extension method, `val webclient.AsyncDownloadString : uri -> Async{string}`:

```
let Download(url : Uri) =
    async {
    let client = new WebClient()
    client.Encoding <- Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")
    let! html = client.AsyncDownloadString(url)
    return html }
```

Unfortunately, the choice of name clashes with the existing webclient method, which can understandably cause confusion. However, I believe all of the F# async extensions begin with `Async*`.

---

**[Edit to add in response to comments:]**

Usually, .NET uses the BeginFoo / EndFoo pattern for concurrency. If the types are right, you can just use `Async.BuildPrimitive beginMethod endMethod`, which will return an Async wrapper for the method.

Sometimes objects don't use this pattern, like the WebClient, and you actually have to use `Async.AwaitEvent` to wait for an event to be fired, or write your own loop to repeatedly check to see if a bool is set. Here's a nice [article on converting events to Async objects](http://codebetter.com/blogs/matthew.podwysocki/archive/2009/09/04/f-first-class-events-async-workflows-events-part-iii.aspx).

For what its worth, if you have F# installed, you should also have the source code which will give you an idea of how the F# team implements their async extensions. On my machine, the relevant file is located at:

```
C:\Program Files\FSharp-1.9.6.16\source\fsppack\FSharp.PowerPack\AsyncOperations.fs
```